# organize the three div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="1">...</div> //div1
    <div class="2">...</div> //div2
    <div class="3">...</div> //div3
</div>
```

is there a way to organize the three div shows like this.

```
div1   div3
div2
```

i have thought it long time.but still don't have any idea.

Comment: Is moving the DIVs around an option?

Comment: remember to write valid markup => close tags (<div></div>) and check attributes (class="group")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="one">div 1</div>
    <div class="three">div 3</div> 
    <div class="two">div 2</div>
</div>

.one, .three{
    float:left;
}
.three{
    margin-left:10px;
}
.two{
    clear:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qw5dr/

Answer (score 2):

Place div1 and div2 in a div-left and div3 in a div-right.

```
<html><body> 
   <div id="page">  
     <div id="content-primary">
       <div class="div1"></div>
       <div class="div2"></div>
     </div> 
     <div id="content-secondary">
       <div class="div3"></div>
     </div> 
   </div> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

and the CSS...

```
body { 
 text-align: center; 
} 
#page { 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width: 960px; 
 text-align: left; 
} 
#content-primary { 
 float: right; 
 width: 60%;
 height:100%;
} 
#content-secondary { 
 float: right; 
 width: 20%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://jsbin.com/ogawi6 .
Placed a `<br>` after the first div and some css

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this: http://jsbin.com/uwuge3

Code:

```
  <div class="group">
    <div class="1" style="float:left;border:1px solid;">div 1</div>
    <div class="3" style="border:1px solid red;">div 3</div>
    <div class="2">div 2</div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use html table to position those DIVs